# What is the $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/ \mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: galois-theory

The minimal irreducible polinomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is $x^3-2$, its roots are $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}$.

So, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ it can't be the splitting field. Therefore the only automorphism that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity, since the other roots are not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you! :)